# In java what's the best way to subtract 1 numeric string from another numeric string

Tags: java

Want to handle following problem

```
String findDifference(String, String)
{
   str1 - str2
}
```

where if

```
   str1 = "1002456789100245678910024567891002456789100245678910024567891002456789100245678910024567891002456789100245678910024567891002456789100245678910024567891002456789";
   str2 = "0022446611002244661100224466110022446611002244661100224466110022446611002244661100224466110022446611002244661100224466110022446611002244661100224466110022446611";
   output = "1000010178100001017810000101781000010178100001017810000101781000010178100001017810000101781000010178100001017810000101781000010178100001017810000101781000010178"

   str1 = "1002456789100245678910024567891002456789100245678910024567891002456789100245678910024567891002456789100245678910024567891002456789100245678910024567891002456789100245678910024567891002456789100245678910024567891002456789";
   str2 = "0022446611000000000000224466110000000000002244661100000000000022446611000000000000224466110000000000002244661100000000000022446611000000000000224466110000000000002244661100000000000022446611000000000000224466110000000000";
   output = "1000010178100245678910000101781002456789100001017810024567891000010178100245678910000101781002456789100001017810024567891000010178100245678910000101781002456789100001017810024567891000010178100245678910000101781002456789"
```

Is there any better/optimized way than Traversing Str1 ctr(0,n-1) Integer.parseInt(str1[ctr]) - Integer.parseInt(str2[ctr]) and appending the answer to output[ctr]?

Will BigInteger handle such big numbers?

Answer (score 3):

You're handing really big numbers - bigger than what can fit into an `int`. If you want to handle arbitrarily big numbers (memory permitting) you need to use BigInteger:

```
public static String findDifference(String str1, String str2) {
    return new BigInteger(str1).subtract(new BigInteger(str2)).toString();
}
```

Note that your examples are wrong - the outputs are not the correct result for `str1 - str2`.

If I use this little driver program:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(findDifference("10024567891002456789", "00224466110000000000"));
    System.out.println(findDifference("1002456789", "0022446611"));
    System.out.println(findDifference("1234567", "0111100"));
}
```

I'm getting this output, and a verification with a calculator shows that this is correct:

```
9800101781002456789
980010178
1123467
```

Comment: Erwin BigInteger may fail for lets say string length is 400+

Comment: @VijayKurhade - Are you asking a question, or making a statement of fact?  If this is a question, then the answer is No (unless your heap is too small),  If this is a statement, please provide some evidence to support it.