# How to convert large numbers in a text file (strings) into ints and add them

Tags: java

How to convert large numbers in a text file (strings) into ints and add them.

> 3123123123123 759345 903470283
>
> 1839282039485028304849404 3839282039485028304849404
>
> 22 32
>
> 9888 9233
>
> 93373849503817264 38394058293045859 38394932293045859
>   93373849503817264
>
> 38394058293045859
>
> 90349329492349      0
>
> 94840
>
> 10000000000000000000 600000
>
> 32453 325235 32
>
> 100 0
>
> 34
>
> 0
>
> 0  0  0

This is the text file I am working with. I need to convert these into ints and add them. I haven't learned parseInt yet, so unless there's any way around it, i'd like to know how to convert these into ints and sum them in each line.

Comment: i see spaces between numbers in each line. are they separate numbers?

Comment: You can't convert `1839282039485028304849404` into an `int`, but a `BigInteger` object might be what you're looking for.

Comment: We cant use BigInteger... and yes, they are separate numbers.

Comment: Well, that is the correct way of doing it.  If you have a teacher who has forbidden you from doing the correct thing, then it would be better to ask _them_ what they have in mind, than ask here.

Comment: Could you show me how to do it using BigInteger. I tried myself and couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Basically, you use the `next` method of `Scanner` to get each number as a `String`, and pass it to the `BigInteger` constructor.

Comment: I still didnt get it. Could you write it out in code?

Comment: do you want to not use `BigInteger` and add them 1 digit at a time and use `Integer.parseInt` to convert each digit to int and add?

Comment: Adding BigIntegers is trivially different from subtracting them, so look at the answer to this question: [In java what's the best way to subtract 1 numeric string from another numeric string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41319677/in-java-whats-the-best-way-to-subtract-1-numeric-string-from-another-numeric-st/41319708#41319708)

Comment: Example of using `BigInteger`: [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/PEGsTL)

Comment: Your question is unclear. Clean up your question and indicate what the true requirements are to be. You say that you need to "convert large numbers in a text file (strings) into ints and add them" and that you can't use the BigInteger data type yet some of the values contained within the supplied sample text file values can not be converted to Integer (the values are far too large for that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this code can help.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // write your code here
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("C:\\directory\\test.txt"));
        List<BigInteger> bigIntegers = new ArrayList<>();
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            bigIntegers.add(new BigInteger(scanner.next()));
        }
        BigInteger total = new BigInteger("0");
        for(BigInteger bigInt: bigIntegers) {
            total = total.add(bigInt);
        }
        System.out.println(total);
    }
```

Comment: I dont understand what the <> are.

Comment: @MooazNasir That is Java 7 diamond operator. Used with generics.

Comment: @moocow - any reason why this has been un-accepted as answer?

Answer (score 0):

Well if you don't want to use big integer you can try something similar to this:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("filename.txt"));
double [] number = new double[100];
int i = 0;
while(scanner.hasNextDouble())
{
    number[i] = scanner.nextDouble();
    i++;
}
```

This will technically store your large integer in an array, from there you can try to decide how to go about it. This is just one way I thought of without using BigInteger.

Comment: i disagree. The numbers shown are outside the range of int in java. so you can't do this.

Comment: You're right, the int wont support that large of a number. You'd have to go digit by digit in order to stuff into an array. Or perhaps use a different data type?

Comment: You have to use big integer or double to store such longer numbers. They are certainly out of range of integer.

Comment: Would changing the code up to use a double array work out because he said that he is not allowed to use BigInteger.

Comment: But `double` is no good here because it only offers 15-16 significant figures, so there are numbers in that file that are too big to be stored accurately in a `double`.  The only options are to use `BigInteger` or `BigDecimal` to store these; or to store them all in `String`s and roll your own addition algorithm.